# reorder specified columns in a data.frame ascending

Tags: r, sorting

I have one short question,
how can I reorder a dataframe only for selected columnnames. I would need a universal solution here because I have to use it on changing amounts of V columns (everytime with V columns >100)

Example:

Consider I have the data:

```
dkk <- structure(list(A = 2L, X = 3L, C = 4L, D = 5L, Z = 6L, V1 = 5L, 
                     V6 = 5L, V4 = 5L, V5 = 5L, V3 = 2L, V2 = 2L), .Names = c("X", 
                                                                              "B", "C", "D", "Z", "V1", "V6", "V4", "V5", "V3", "V2"), 
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L)) 

# X B C D Z V1 V6 V4 V5 V3 V2
  2 3 4 5 6  5  5  5  5  2  2
```

How can I reorder the columns with a V so that they are in a ascending order:

```
# X B C D Z V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
  2 3 4 5 6  5  2  2  5  5  5
```

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a faster option with `setcolorder` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
i1 <- grep("V\\d+", names(dkk), value = TRUE)
cbind(dkk[setdiff(names(dkk), i1)], setcolorder(dkk[i1], order(i1))[])
#  A B C D Z V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
#1 2 3 4 5 6  5  2  2  5  5  5
```

---

This becomes a bit complicated when the 'V' names are intermingled with other columns, for example suppose, we change the column names to

```
set.seed(24)
names(dkk) <- sample(names(dkk))
dkk
#   D C V6 Z V4 V1 B V2 V3 A V5
#1 2 3  4 5  6  5 5  5  5 2  2
```

Now, the option is to create a numeric index of those columns with 'V' ('i2'), extract the names ('i3') and assign the order of names and columns separately

```
i2 <- grep("^V\\d+", names(dkk))
i3 <- names(dkk)[i2]
names(dkk)[i2] <- sort(names(dkk)[i2])
dkk[i2] <- dkk[i2][order(i3)]
```

to get

```
dkk
#  D C V1 Z V2 V3 B V4 V5 A V6
#1 2 3  5 5  5  5 5  6  2 2  4
```

#### Update

There was one glitch in the above solution.  It doesn't do the `sort`ing correctly when we have column names with numbers greater than 9 i.e. 'V10', 'V11', etc.  Suppose, our third column name is 'V100'

```
colnames(dkk)[3] <- "V100"   
dkk
#  D C V100 Z V4 V1 B V2 V3 A V5
#1 2 3    4 5  6  5 5  5  5 2  2

i2 <- grep("^V\\d+", names(dkk))
i3 <- names(dkk)[i2]
```

We can parse the number part with `parse_number` to assist in ordering

```
i4 <- readr::parse_number(i3)
names(dkk)[i2] <- i3[order(i4)]
dkk[i2] <- dkk[i2][order(i4)]
dkk
#  D C V1 Z V2 V3 B V4 V5 A V100
#1 2 3  5 5  5  5 5  6  2 2    4
```

#### data

```
dkk <- structure(list(A = 2L, B = 3L, C = 4L, D = 5L, E = 6L, V1 = 5L,
                 V6 = 5L, V4 = 5L, V5 = 5L, V3 = 2L, V2 = 2L), .Names = c("A",
                                                                          "B", "C", "D", "Z", "V1", "V6", "V4", "V5", "V3", "V2"),
            class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this with `order` on colnames:

```
dkk[,order(colnames(dkk))]

  A B C D E V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
  2 3 4 5 6  5  2  2  5  5  5
```

**EDIT** To order only columns that contain "V". Note: I included a Z column in the data set. Basically, I `c` the columns names that do not need to be sorted to the "V" columns that are sorted.

```
dkk <- structure(list(A = 2L, B = 3L, C = 4L, D = 5L, E = 6L, V1 = 5L,
                     V6 = 5L, V4 = 5L, V5 = 5L, V3 = 2L, V2 = 2L), .Names = c("A",
                                                                              "B", "C", "D", "Z", "V1", "V6", "V4", "V5", "V3", "V2"),
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L))

cols <- c(colnames(dkk)[!grepl("V",names(dkk))],
colnames(dkk)[grepl("V",names(dkk))][order(colnames(dkk)[grepl("V",names(dkk))])])

dkk[,cols]

  A B C D Z V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
1 2 3 4 5 6  5  2  2  5  5  5
```

Comment: Thanks, this works fine when I have this names (A,B,C,D,E,V1:Vend) but what can I do when I have (A,X,C,D,Z,V1:Vend) as this will put X and Z behind all V`s?